# How to create Named colors in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, assets, xcode9

How do I setup & use custom named colors in Interface Builder?

[image: Named colors in IB]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Xcode9 you can add **"New Color Set"** to **.xcassets** files, where you can set rgba values or use IB's color picker.

[image: Add new Color set to Assets.xcassets in Xcode 9]

Then you can use that newly defined color from Interface Builder's color picker, it appears under the **Named Colors** section.

[image: yourCustomColor appears in IB's color picker, under Named colors section]

Or you can use it from code like `UIColor(named:"customColorName")`.

As for now, Xcode9 beta 1 does not support using string literal color names as UIColor (like it works with UIImages), but I hope it will work in a later release.

---

Unfortunatelly it's only available for iOS11 and later.
[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! It helped me a lot!!
Is it backward compatible with iOS 8,9?

Comment: Unforutnatelly it's not backward compatible.

Comment: In iOS 10 app crashes with not so obvious error message "Could not instantiate class named _UIColorAttributeTraitStorage".

Comment: Does anyone succeeded in using the same technique in macOS project?

Comment: No, not so far, unfortunately :(

Comment: TOo bad it is not backward compatible.

Comment: Yes, it crashed on iOS 10, so I wrote a shell which will batch replace Named colors to RGB when Xcode build.

Comment: Anyone got any alternate solution because only 52% iPhones users are using iOS 11.

Comment: @Artwalk could you please explain more