# Backgroundcolor Doesn't change?

Tags: ios, iphone, delegates, swift4.2

i have sended a color name with a delegate from a different ViewController and the data recieves successfully(printed the right color). Then if I want to change the backroundcolor of the view itself then with that name that I received but it didn't work.

```
func sendColor(color: String) {
    let colorLowercased = color.lowercased()
    print(colorLowercased)

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "\(colorLowercased)")
    print(view.backgroundColor)
}
```

and the code execute

after changing the backgroundcolor is nil and the view is black

in the colorviewController here's my delegate function to send

```
@IBAction func colorPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let selectedColor = sender.currentTitle

    if let delegate = delegate {
        delegate.sendColor(color: selectedColor!)
    }

    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

btw im using swift 4.2

Comment: You have to create a mapping between the name and the respective `UIColor`.

Comment: what is a mapping?

Comment: A dictionary maybe? Which says "green" -> UIColor.green, "red" -> UIColor.red, etc

Comment: Short answer: Your approach will not work. You cannot get a color from a string value which is a color name. That initializer is for getting the color from an asset.

Comment: oh. what should I do then

Comment: What the first comment says. Once you map all possible strings that can occur as title to the respective colors, just get color from the mapping and set the background color.

Comment: you're right but what is if I have 100 colors?

Comment: You create a map for 100 colors or find some other way which doesn't involve a string to get the color from. How do you set the title for the button btw?

Comment: a dictionary for 100 colors is too much work. In the storyboard I set the title

Comment: If you set the title in the storyboard you will only have 1 title? When do you change it? And what conditions do you use to change or reset it?

Comment: but the problem is btw that I want the exact button color not the default green

Comment: If you want the button color then why are you getting the button title?

Comment: idk im dump hahah. I fixed it now. Its working now thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is black because your code is trying to set `view.backgroundColor` with a color which is likely nil. Do you have `named` colors in your app asset? To add them you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625223/how-to-create-named-colors-in-interface-builder) . Alternatively, instead of passing title to your `sendColor:` pass the color of your button (title color/bgColor/tintColor).

`func sendColor(color: UIColor)`